# NoSuchMethodError: 'org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlOptions

Tags: java, maven

as the title suggests, i am getting a no such method error when running a process in my application.

Unsure as to how i am getting this - i have checked my pom.xml and ran a mvn dependency tree on it. It does download this dependency as a required dependency, it is also in my lib folder when i unpack my .War file.

if you need any more info, just ask away

Stuff i have tried

- I have ran a mvn clean install -U
- manually putting in the dependency

here is the error in full for a bit more info

```
23-Jan-2024 16:34:43.680 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service() for servlet [secure] in context with path [/ekb-gms] threw exception [Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlOptions org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlOptions.setEntityExpansionLimit(int)'] with root cause
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlOptions org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlOptions.setEntityExpansionLimit(int)'
        at org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLTypeLoader.<clinit>(POIXMLTypeLoader.java:43)
        at org.apache.poi.xssf.model.ThemesTable.<init>(ThemesTable.java:86)
        at org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLFactory.createDocumentPart(POIXMLFactory.java:61)
        at org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLDocumentPart.read(POIXMLDocumentPart.java:660)
        at org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLDocument.load(POIXMLDocument.java:165)
        at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.<init>(XSSFWorkbook.java:278)
        at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbookFactory.createWorkbook(XSSFWorkbookFactory.java:118)
        at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbookFactory.create(XSSFWorkbookFactory.java:98)
        at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbookFactory.create(XSSFWorkbookFactory.java:36)
        at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.lambda$create$2(WorkbookFactory.java:199)
        at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.wp(WorkbookFactory.java:295)
        at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(WorkbookFactory.java:199)
        at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(WorkbookFactory.java:163)
        at com.amor.ekb.service.capacitycurve.SpreadsheetParser.parseSpreadsheet(SpreadsheetParser.java:42)
        at com.amor.ekb.service.capacitycurve.CapacityCurveServiceImpl.updateCapacityCurve_aroundBody0(CapacityCurveServiceImpl.java:84)
        at com.amor.ekb.service.capacitycurve.CapacityCurveServiceImpl$AjcClosure1.run(CapacityCurveServiceImpl.java:1)
        at org.springframework.transaction.aspectj.AbstractTransactionAspect.ajc$around$org_springframework_transaction_aspectj_AbstractTransactionAspect$1$2a73e96cproceed(AbstractTransactionAspect.aj:66)
        at org.springframework.transaction.aspectj.AbstractTransactionAspect$AbstractTransactionAspect$1.proceedWithInvocation(AbstractTransactionAspect.aj:72)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:283)
        at org.springframework.transaction.aspectj.AbstractTransactionAspect.ajc$around$org_springframework_transaction_aspectj_AbstractTransactionAspect$1$2a73e96c(AbstractTransactionAspect.aj:70)
        at com.amor.ekb.service.capacitycurve.CapacityCurveServiceImpl.updateCapacityCurve(CapacityCurveServiceImpl.java:70)
        at com.amor.ekb.web.mvc.capacitycurve.CapacityCurveController.save(CapacityCurveController.java:194)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:204)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:854)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:765)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:555)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:623)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:209)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:317)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
        at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
        at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
        at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
        at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:66)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
        at org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter.doFilter(ConcurrentSessionFilter.java:155)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:347)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:263)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.web.Log4jServletFilter.doFilter(Log4jServletFilter.java:71)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:168)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:481)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:130)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:670)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:390)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:928)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1794)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't shown your Maven `pom.xml`. But the error in your stacktrace is quite self-explanatory.

```
NoSuchMethodError: 'org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlOptions org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlOptions.setEntityExpansionLimit(int)'
```

As the error states, the method `setEntityExpansionLimit` is not found in the class `org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlOptions`. The Apache XMLBeans veresion that you are using is old (<=2.6.0).

In order to resolve this issue, just get a newer version in your pom.xml. E.g. the version [5.0.0](https://xmlbeans.apache.org/docs/5.0.0/org/apache/xmlbeans/XmlOptions.html#setEntityExpansionLimit(int)) has this method. So add the following dependency in your pom.xml.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.xmlbeans</groupId>
        <artifactId>xmlbeans</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: lol, yup you were right. It was downloading an older version.

Answer (score 0):

You may check:

- classpath
- JAVA_HOME